# PHP function doesn't return null but doesn't return anything either

Tags: php

Here is my code, which uses an extended phpMailer.  This works if I check for firstResult and lastResult, but not if I check for emailResult:

```
$validator = new FormValidator();
            $firstResult = $validator->checkFirst($_POST['firstname']);
            $lastResult = $validator->checkLast($_POST['lastname']);
            $emailResult = $validator->checkEmail($_POST['emailaddress1']);
            var_dump($emailResult);
            if (is_null($firstResult) && is_null($lastResult) && is_null($emailResult)) {

                $mail = new ULSMail();

                $mail->IsSMTP();  // telling the class to use SMTP
                $mail->AddAddress("shummel@ulsinc.com");

                $mail->Subject  = "test";
                $mail->MsgHTML($messageHTML);

                redirectULS('english/forms/thankyou.php');

                if(!$mail->Send()) {
                    echo 'Message was not sent.';
                    echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
                } else {

                    //$bridge->pushLead($lead);
                }
            } else {
                //...
            }
```

and in my FormValidator class:

```
function checkEmail($email){

        if(strlen(trim($email)) < 8){
        return 'Please enter a valid email address of more than 8 characters</span>';
    } else {
        return NULL;
    }

}
```

redirectULS is a simple redirect function for internal redirects on my site.  It works as long as I don't check for $emailResult.

Comment: how do you know it does not return NULL?

Comment: I test for it elsewhere and the test returns some kind of value, but not one I can seem to output.

Comment: If using PHP 5.2 or higher, it now has built in email checks - http://uk.php.net/filter_var

Comment: Some small advice..let the function return true or false. This will make it more reusable. Let the script that calls the function determine if to show the errortext or do something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Actually, it does!](http://ideone.com/hkdTV)

```
if (checkEmail("123456789") === NULL)
  print "Actually, it does!\n";
```

What you're doing is printing the result directly, which will cast `NULL` to an empty string. Hence it only appears to return nothing.

Notice that I made use of the [triple equals operator](http://www.wellho.net/mouth/863_Double-and-Triple-equals-operator-in-PHP.html), which tests for equality in value AND type. As @Tomcat suggests, you can also use [`is_null()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php)

Comment: But if I test for whether it is null, it tests as not null if $email is 8 characters or longer.

Comment: @shummel How are you testing for `NULL`? The above code disagrees with you.

Comment: @shummel7845 That means your test for null is wrong. Try marcog's example code.

Comment: @marcog Just as I was about to edit it ... definitely use ===, not ==, to check for NULL.

Comment: @phihag Yes, I just realised PHP had the `===` operator. My PHP is a little rusty.

Comment: I'm using is_null.  Other thoughts?

Comment: @Tomcat Edited that in as an alternative. @shummel What more do you need? We've shown you it is returning `NULL`.

Comment: @shummel7845 Check that you're actually calling the version of checkEmail you posted here. Additionally, use var_dump to find out what is actually returned. If you still think checkEmail does not return NULL, please post slightly longer code that outputs either "is null" or "is not null".

Comment: As mentioned in my answer, and in both James' and Oli's comments; you may want to reconsider your validation method. Either via filter or regular expressions. I suggest the latter, as familiarizing yourself with regular expressions (if you aren't already) is always advantageous. Returning a boolean value `true`/`false` is highly suggested also.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it returns `NULL` when your string is lower than 8.
Try `var_dump` instead of `echo`/`print`, it should display the "real" value (=`NULL`) of your string.

Answer (score 0):

How are you testing the return?

```
echo is_null(checkEmail('foo@bar.com')) ? 'Pass' : 'Fail';
```

Also just a note; your validation parameters of 8 characters will fail on an email such as `j@cc.tv`. While surely rare, it would be suggested you validate based on form using Regular Expressions. Plenty of [examples](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html) on the web.

---

```
class Validator{

    public function checkEmail($email){
        return preg_match('/^[^@]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z]+$/', $email);
    }

    public function checkName($name){
        return preg_match('/[a-z]{2,}/i', $name); //valid if $name is 2+ A-Z characters
    }

}

$v = new Validator;
if($v->checkEmail($_POST['email'])
&& $v->checkName($_POST['fname'])
&& $v->checkName($_POST['lname'])){
    //the info is valid
}else{
    //the info is not valid
}
```

Comment: It'll also fail on `123456789` as my answer showed without actually pointing it out. :)

Comment: Tomcat--I'm open to using your function above but what does it return?  Is it true if it matches and false if it doesn't?

Comment: @shummel7845; That's correct. making it easy to use `if(validateEmail($user_email)){ ... }`, though you may want to explore other regex patterns. I just pulled that one from PHP doc comments. There are far stricter and looser ones, and you'll surely be able to find or create one that fits your needs.

Comment: Tomcat, here is what is troubling me:  $emailResult = $validator->validateEmail($_POST['emailaddress1']);
    
    if (is_null($firstResult) && is_null($lastResult) && $emailResult != FALSE) { ...}  The code in the braces never gets executed unless I remove the email part.  Thoughts?  I've also tried $emailResult = TRUE and $emailResult.

Comment: Well, I'm not certain of how `$firstResult` is determined; I'm guessing you're using a function similar to your email validation of previous. My suggestion is to modify your other validation functions to return boolean values also, therefore allowing your condition to be `if($validator->checkFirst($first) && $validator->checkLast($last) && $validator->checkEmail($email)){ stuff_is_valid(); }`. Note, I've modified the naming conventions for consistency, something I strongly suggest you do also :)

Comment: I've modified my answer with a more comprehensive example.